# Runtime error in Java: half of all console inputs are recorded in text file

Tags: java, do-while, prepend

```
package addlinenumbers;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AddLineNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0;

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream ("dataInput.txt", true)) {
            try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos)) {
                String userInput = " ";
                do {
                    System.out.print("Enter string to prepend to 'dataInput.txt'; -1 to EXIT: ");
                    userInput = input.nextLine();
                    if (!userInput.equals("-1")) {
                        pw.println(input.nextLine());
                        i++;
                    }
                } while(!(userInput.equals("-1")));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("Unable to find dataInput.txt...");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally { 
                System.out.println("# of objects prepended: " + i);
                System.out.println("Closing file...");
        }
    }
}






****************************OUTPUT**********************************************
    run:
    Please enter strings to prepend to 'dataInput.txt'; -1 to EXIT: 
    David
    Goliath
    Please enter strings to prepend to 'dataInput.txt'; -1 to EXIT: 
    Delilah
    Samson
    Please enter strings to prepend to 'dataInput.txt'; -1 to EXIT: 
    -1
    # of objects prepended: 2
    Closing file...
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 18 seconds)
```

As you can see, it takes in only TWO objects they are "Goliath" and "Samson" and they are the only strings written to the text file. Technically it should have 4 objects and "David" and "Delilah" *should* be in the text file also, but they're not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are calling `input.nextLine()` twice per iteration, you should do it only once .

Comment: `pw.println(input.nextLine());` should be `pw.println(userInput);`

Comment: thank you MP. i'm gonna go to bed now.